# Adding user property in Firebase Analytics as a secondary column

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, firebase-analytics, google-analytics-4

We have recently migrated our iOS app to use Firebase Analytics from Google Analytics

Within GA, we had a custom dimension which is now being sent through the SDK as a user property

Without using BigQuery, is there a way in the Firebase Console to view screen views and/or events with the user property as a secondary data item? Not as a filter, but to add as a column to the report in the same way as you can add a secondary dimension in GA

Or is Firebase now deprecating functionality to force you to start using and paying for BigQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect Firebase with Google Analytics 4 and in `Explore --> Analysis` report, anyway for custom analysis, the better way currently is export raw data to `BigQuery` and use that.